# biblatex symbol instead numbers

Tags: biblatex, symbols

I am using `biblatex` and I want to use a symbol instead the numbers.
Consider this example

[1] Adimurthi, Jerome Jaffre, and G. D. Veerappa Gowda. Godunov-type methods for conservation laws with a flux function discontinuous in space. SIAM J. Numer. Anal., 42(1):179–208 (electronic), 2004.

[2] Clarisse Alboin, Jerome Jaffre, Jean E. Roberts, Xuewen Wang, and Christophe Serres. Domain decomposition for some transmission problems in flow in porous media, volume 552 of Lecture Notes in Phys., pages 22–34. Springer, Berlin, 2000.

Instead the number I want a symbol, common for all the entry. For example

● Adimurthi, Jerome Jaffre, and G. D. Veerappa Gowda. Godunov-type methods for conservation laws with a flux function discontinuous in space. SIAM J. Numer. Anal., 42(1):179–208 (electronic), 2004.

● Clarisse Alboin, Jerome Jaffre, Jean E. Roberts, Xuewen Wang, and Christophe Serres. Domain decomposition for some transmission problems in flow in porous media, volume 552 of Lecture Notes in Phys., pages 22–34. Springer, Berlin, 2000.

There is an easy way to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: What will the citations look like? Or will you be using `\nocite`?

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\textbullet~}
\begin{document}

\nocite{aksin,bertram,chiu}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

and without a hanging indentation:

```
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\textbullet}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alan and Herbert, plain and simple solution!

Answer (score 6):

Since this sort of bibliography only makes sense if you don't actually have citations, I'm assuming it's for a CV or publications list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{\textbullet}}
            {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1}

\begin{document}    
\nocite{aksin,bertram,chiu}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]